# How to record streaks in loops - making odds calculator

Tags: math, lua, coronasdk

I'm making an odds calculator. I'm trying to print the highest streak a player would win, and streak average.

When i'm referring to streak, I mean how many times does the player win in a row before the opposition wins 1 and vice versa.

I'm doing 40% vs 60% odds FYI.

```
while (nFlip <= 99) do

    nFlip = nFlip + b 

    if math.random(0,4) < 2 then
        countPlayer = countPlayer + b
--!!!!! How to record player streak and player average
        print( "Player Wins" )
    elseif math.random(0,4) < 3 then
        countHouse = countHouse + b
 --!!!!! How to record player streak and player average
        print( "House Wins" )
    end

end
```

Comment: So you want it so that at the end of the `while` loop it tells you the highest streak and average of both the house and the player?

Comment: Right on the nose, correct.

Comment: Use arrays storing the streaks, and then do a `for k,v in pairs()` to loop through and find the highest and calculate the average.

Comment: `elseif math.random(0,4) < 3 then` should be just `else`

Answer (score 0):

If the definition of a streak is the number of consecutive wins, then compute that, and store in a table.

```
local playerStreak = 0
local houseStreak = 0
local playerStreaks = {}
local houseStreaks = {}
local nFlip = 0

math.randomseed(os.time())

while nFlip <= 99 do
    nFlip = nFlip + 1

    local r = math.random()
    local playerWinProb = 0.4
    if r < playerWinProb then -- player wins!
        playerStreak = playerStreak + 1
        if houseStreak > 0 then -- house won last, end of its streak
            table.insert(houseStreaks, houseStreak)
            houseStreak = 0
        end
        -- print( "Player Wins" )
    else
        houseStreak = houseStreak + 1
        if playerStreak > 0 then -- house won last, end of its streak
            table.insert(playerStreaks, playerStreak)
            playerStreak = 0
        end
        -- print( "House Wins" )
    end
end

table.sort(playerStreaks)
print('largest player streak:', playerStreaks[#playerStreaks])
table.sort(houseStreaks)
print('largest house streak:', houseStreaks[#houseStreaks])
```

After all the flips, you can compute stats:

- for the largest player streak, search `playerStreaks` for largest value (I was lazy and used a sort instead, not as efficient but not bad either); similarly for largest house streak
- for average, sum up all player streaks and divide by `#playerStreaks`; similarly for house streak
- etc.